# Cmake 'check_include_files' function failed when files exist

Tags: c, cmake

Assume we have a CMakeLists.txt who has code like ( following is little part of whole file ):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.3)
#...
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -I/usr/include/mit-krb5/")
message("CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES=${CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES};CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS=${CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS};CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS=${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS}")
message("before find path, fuckGssApiIncludes=${fuckGssApiIncludes}")
find_path(fuckGssApiIncludes "gssapi.h" "/usr/include")
if(NOT fuckGssApiIncludes)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't find folder containing gssapi.h")
endif()
message("after, fuckGssApiIncludes=${fuckGssApiIncludes}")
include_directories(${fuckGssApiIncludes})
check_include_files("gssapi.h" HAVE_GSSAPI_H)
#....
if (NOT HAVE_GSSAPI_H)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find GSS libraries")
```

And we have some files:

```
# ls /usr/include/gssapi.h
/usr/include/gssapi.h
```

But when I run this command with **cmake version 3.12.1**, I got error like this:

```
CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES=/usr/include/;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/;CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS=;CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS=
before find path, fuckGssApiIncludes=
after, fuckGssApiIncludes=/usr/include
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:548 (message):
  Cannot find GSS libraries
```

I thought in someway, Cmake.check_include_files did not works as Cmake's definition.

So, **Q1: Is my thought correct, and why?**  **Q2: How to work around, and make this cmakelists.txt run well?**

Answer (score 1):

Answer find, just remove all cmake temporary files.